# emacs24 error Timeout while querying Python for system include path

Tags: python, emacs24

Today, I installed emacs24.3, but some problems occurred. Some problems resolved with the help of Google, but I can not sovle the following problem. I installed pymacs, rope and yasnippets, when I open an python file(*.py), an error occurred:

```
Timeout while querying Python for system include path.
```

How I should solve the problem? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised by CEDET (cf. *semantic/wisent/python.el*), which is included in Emacs 24.3.
For me, explicitly setting CEDET's **python-shell-interpreter** variable before any CEDET files are loaded works.  The line from my ~/.emacs is:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/python")
```

where */path/to/python* on my system happens to be */opt/bin/python*.